# Как расположить блоки слева?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Как разместить блоки с акциями и т.д. на одном уровне с блоком footer-logo

```css
.footer{
    padding-top: 59px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    background: #D10000;
    width: 100%;
}

.footer-container{
    width: 1180px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer-left{
    display: block;
    margin-top: -55px;
}

.footer-phone{
    margin: 12px 0 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 28px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700; 
    padding-left: 22px;
}

.phone-footer{
    margin: 5px 0 0;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

.phone-footer a{
    color: #fff;
}

ul.menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18%;
    margin-top: 15px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}
ul.menu li a i.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  transition: all ease 0.2s;
}
ul.menu li a i.fa::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color:  #F6B300;
}
ul.menu li a i.fa:hover {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
}
ul.menu li a i.fa:hover::after {
  animation: animate ease 0.6s forwards;
}
ul.menu li a i.fa-facebook:hover::after {
  background-color: #3b5998;
}
ul.menu li a i.fa-vk:hover::after {
  background-color: #00aced;
}
ul.menu li a i.fa-instagram:hover::after {
  background-color: #8a3ab9;
}


@keyframes animate {
  0%, 20% {
    transform: scale(1);
    border-radius: 40px;
    background-color:  #fff;;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  60%, 100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
}

.footer-right{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.footer-akcii{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: -35px;
    margin-right: 860px;
     position: relative;
}

.footer-link{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 31px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.footer-link:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-underline-position: under;
}

.footer-shop{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

.content{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-left: 15px;
       }


.content1{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: -15px;
        
       }
```

```html
 <div class="footer">
       <div class="footer-container">
           <div class="footer-left">
           <a href="#" class="footer-logo">
               <img src="img/astfooter.svg">
           </a>
           <div class="phone-footer">
              <a href="tel:+77479009999" class="footer-phone"> +7 747 900 99 99 </a>
               <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/Astykzhan.astana"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="https://vk.com/astykzhankostgroup"><i class="fa fa-vk"></i></a></li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/astykzhan/?hl=ru"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
</ul>
           </div>
           </div>
           <div class="footer-right">
              <div class="foot-content">
                   <div><a href="#" class="footer-link"> Акции</a></div>
                   <div><a href="#" class="footer-link"> Поставщикам</a></div>
          </div>  `
                <div class="foot-content1">
                   <div><a href="#" class="footer-link"> О нас</a></div>
                   <div><a href="#" class="footer-link"> Поставщикам</a></div>
                   <div><a href="#" class="footer-link"> Юрлицам</a></div>
          </div>  `
           <div class="foot-content2">
                   <div><a href="#" class="footer-link"> Оплата</a></div>
                   <div><a href="#" class="footer-link"> Бонусы</a></div>
                   <div><a href="#" class="footer-link"> Доставка и возврат</a></div>
          </div> 
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`margin-top: -55px;` из `.footer-left {...}` уберите.